# java background transparent

Tags: java, background, png, transparent, gif

I have a gif image which contains only a colored shape, and a transparent background.

I would like to replace the shape's color by the one I want (the color pallet for this gif is only 2 colors: transparent and white in my case).

I've created a filter which correctly replace white with red (this is a test).

However I'm encountering an issue with my method imageToBufferedImage, it removes the transparency and replace it with black (don't know why).

So what I've done so far is this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.awt.image.ImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.awt.image.RGBImageFilter;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TestPNG {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File in = new File("bg.gif");
        BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(in);
        int color = source.getRGB(0, 0);

        Image image = makeColorTransparent(source, new Color(color), new Color(255, 0, 0));

        BufferedImage transparent = imageToBufferedImage(image);

        File out = new File("bg2.gif");
        ImageIO.write(transparent, "gif", out);

    }

    private static BufferedImage imageToBufferedImage(Image image) {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        //g2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 40);
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
        return bufferedImage;
    }

    public static Image makeColorTransparent(BufferedImage im, final Color search, final Color replace) {
        ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
                public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
                        if (rgb == search.getRGB()) {
                            return replace.getRGB();
                        } else {
                            return rgb;
                        }
                }
        };
        ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
    }

}
```

Comment: I need to specify that removing the filter still causes the same issue of black color instead of transparency
So the issue come either from Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(im.getSource()) or from the imageToBufferedImage method

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1) Replace

```
Image image = makeColorTransparent(source, new Color(color), new Color(255, 0, 0));
```

with

```
Image image = makeColorTransparent(source, color, new Color(255, 0, 0));
```

and

```
public static Image makeColorTransparent(BufferedImage im, final Color search, final Color replace) {
...
if (rgb == search.getRGB()) {
...
}
```

with

```
public static Image makeColorTransparent(BufferedImage im, final int search, final Color replace) {
...
if (rgb == search) {
...
}
```

BECAUSE for some reason, the `source.getRGB(0, 0)` ignores alpha value and it becomes white ((255, 255, 255, 0) becomes (255, 255, 255, 255))

2) You can't use `int color = source.getRGB(0, 0)`, because it uses the color of first pixel (transparent). You should use some other code (like asking for the color in console) to find out what pixel's color to store in `int color`

3) You are clearing the color of `BufferedImage bufferedImage` in `imageToBufferedImage(...)` with `Color.BLACK` (default). Replace `//g2.setBackground(Color.blue);` with `g2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));` or remove the `g2.clearRect(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Sure your image supports an alpha channel?
Tried drawing a non-black full size rectangle into bufferedImage first?

Comment: the image used for testing is available here :
[link](http://data.imagup.com/4/1113836851.gif)

Comment: What I meant is this line: `Image image = makeColorTransparent(source, new Color(color), new Color(255, 0, 0));` You're using only RGB colors here, so I assume the alpha channel is not supported-

Comment: adding the alpha parameter changes nothing to the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing:

a) Maybe you don't need the `clearRect(...)` method.

b) Maybe you can use something like:

```
g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
g2.fillRect(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

From the Javadoc for this method:

> Transparent pixels in the image do not affect whatever pixels are already there.

Since you cleared your image, filling it with the background colour, the pixels are already black so they stay black.

Try

```
g2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0) );
g2.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 40);
```

before painting your image.

Comment: doing this isn't working
it removes the transparency from the color palet, so my image is now fully red

Comment: @Bouki: can you provide the gif?

Comment: the image used for testing is available here :
[link](http://data.imagup.com/4/1113836851.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You clear out the pixels with the use of a composite. You can't just paint transparent pixels over other pixels or any of that trash. The Porter-Duff rules are clear, doing any of that will cause pixels to mix according to the composite rule. So just change, the rule clear the pixels.

The problem is most of the solutions are trying to coax the image into getting the pixels you want at the end, using the rule. Change the rule for a second and everything gets way easier.

```
Composite composite = g.getComposite();

g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.CLEAR));
g.fillRect(0, 0, bufferedimage.getWidth(), bufferedimage.getHeight());

g.setComposite(composite);
```

That will clear a graphics object of the current pixels. Then just paint back on what you want. My example restored the previous composite as you'll be surprised how often that stuff goes weird, this way you just get cleared pixels and can start over without changing anything with the graphics context.